# Testing output of void main with Console.readline() involved

Tags: java, junit, console, mockito

I need to junit test an existing code by the output ( in system.out )

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   Console console = System.console();
   String str = console.readLine();
   System.out.println("halo"+str);

}
```

Since the console.readline is waiting for user input, I found it will halt in the console.readline(),thus block me from getting the output.

Is there a way to do this? Is it posible to do it using Mockito or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nearly impossible to test code that works with `System.console()`, because you `System.console()` always retuns `null` in tests. Additionally `Console` is final class without a public constructor.

I recommend to work with the writers and readers of `Console` and test the code that works with the writers and readers.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   Console console = System.console();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(console.reader());
   main2(reader, console.writer(), args);
}

static void main2(BufferedReader reader, Writer writer, String args[] {
   String str = reader.readline();
   System.out.println("halo"+str);
}
```

Output to `System.out` can be tested with the `StandardOutputStreamLog` rule of the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/) library. But in your code it is much easier to write to the `Console`'s writer instead of `System.out`.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method is not a good candidate for unit testing. It is just an entry point for an application. Probably, you need to refactor your class to some kind of dependency injection. For example:

```
public class Something {

    private final LinesProvider linesProvider;

    public Something(LinesProvider linesProvider) {
        this.linesProvider = linesProvider;
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        String str = linesProvider.readLine();
        System.out.println("halo "+str);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Something(new LinesProvider() {
            private final Console console = System.console();
            @Override
            public String readLine() {
                return console.readLine();
                }
        }).sayHello();
    }
}

interface LinesProvider {
    String readLine();
}
```

Then, you can test the system output like shown below, though it's not a good practice. Instead, try to separate I/O logic from application logic:

```
public class TestSomething {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream, true);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setOut(printStream);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        new Something(new LinesProvider() {
            @Override
            public String readLine() {
                return "Vasya";
            }
        }).sayHello();

        assertEquals("halo Vasya" + System.getProperty("line.separator"), new String(outputStream.toByteArray()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following test will work, using the JMockit mocking API:

```
@Test
public void testMyApp(@Mocked final Console console)
{
    new NonStrictExpectations(System.class) {{
        System.console(); result = console;
        console.readLine(); result = " test";
    }};

    OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(output));

    MyApp.main(new String[0]);

    String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    assertEquals("halo test" + lineSep, output.toString());
}
```